# com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastException: Service with name 'hz:impl:jetService' not found

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-jet

I am trying to execute a sample code provided for the Hazelcast Jet on https://blog.hazelcast.com/use-hazelcast-jet-stream-data-imap-kafka-topic/

But its failing with an exception for

> Service with name 'hz:impl:jetService' not found!

Here's my stack trace for the same

```
Mar 07, 2018 1:22:17 PM com.hazelcast.jet.impl.config.XmlJetConfigLocator
INFO: Loading hazelcast-jet-default.xml from classpath.
Mar 07, 2018 1:22:17 PM com.hazelcast.jet.impl.config.XmlJetConfigLocator
INFO: Loading hazelcast.xml from classpath.
Mar 07, 2018 1:22:17 PM com.hazelcast.config.AbstractXmlConfigHelper
WARNING: Name of the hazelcast schema location incorrect using default
Mar 07, 2018 1:22:18 PM com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker
INFO: [LOCAL] [dev] [0.5.1] Interfaces is disabled, trying to pick one address from TCP-IP config addresses: [127.0.0.1]
Mar 07, 2018 1:22:18 PM com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker
INFO: [LOCAL] [dev] [0.5.1] Picked [127.0.0.1]:5702, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,localport=5702], bind any local is true
Mar 07, 2018 1:22:18 PM com.hazelcast.system
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [0.5.1] Hazelcast 3.9 (20171023 - b29f549) starting at [127.0.0.1]:5702
Mar 07, 2018 1:22:18 PM com.hazelcast.system
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [0.5.1] Copyright (c) 2008-2017, Hazelcast, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Mar 07, 2018 1:22:18 PM com.hazelcast.system
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [0.5.1] Configured Hazelcast Serialization version: 1
Mar 07, 2018 1:22:18 PM com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.BackpressureRegulator
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [0.5.1] Backpressure is disabled
Mar 07, 2018 1:22:18 PM com.hazelcast.instance.Node
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [0.5.1] Creating TcpIpJoiner
JetInstanceImpl
Mar 07, 2018 1:22:18 PM com.hazelcast.jet.impl.JetService
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [0.5.1] Starting Jet 0.5.1 (20171206 - a2156c6)
Mar 07, 2018 1:22:18 PM com.hazelcast.jet.impl.JetService
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [0.5.1] Setting number of cooperative threads and default parallelism to 8
Mar 07, 2018 1:22:18 PM com.hazelcast.jet.impl.JetService
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [0.5.1] 
    o   o   o   o---o o---o o     o---o   o   o---o o-o-o        o o---o o-o-o
    |   |  / \     /  |     |     |      / \  |       |          | |       |  
    o---o o---o   o   o-o   |     o     o---o o---o   |          | o-o     |  
    |   | |   |  /    |     |     |     |   |     |   |      \   | |       |  
    o   o o   o o---o o---o o---o o---o o   o o---o   o       o--o o---o   o   
Mar 07, 2018 1:22:18 PM com.hazelcast.jet.impl.JetService
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [0.5.1] Copyright (c) 2008-2017, Hazelcast, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Mar 07, 2018 1:22:18 PM com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [0.5.1] Starting 8 partition threads and 5 generic threads (1 dedicated for priority tasks)
Mar 07, 2018 1:22:18 PM com.hazelcast.internal.diagnostics.Diagnostics
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [0.5.1] Diagnostics disabled. To enable add -Dhazelcast.diagnostics.enabled=true to the JVM arguments.
Mar 07, 2018 1:22:18 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [0.5.1] [127.0.0.1]:5702 is STARTING
Mar 07, 2018 1:22:19 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [0.5.1] Connecting to /127.0.0.1:5703, timeout: 0, bind-any: true
Mar 07, 2018 1:22:19 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [0.5.1] Connecting to /127.0.0.1:5701, timeout: 0, bind-any: true
Mar 07, 2018 1:22:19 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnectionManager
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [0.5.1] Established socket connection between /127.0.0.1:2770 and /127.0.0.1:5701
Mar 07, 2018 1:22:20 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [0.5.1] Could not connect to: /127.0.0.1:5703. Reason: SocketException[Connection refused: connect to address /127.0.0.1:5703]
Mar 07, 2018 1:22:20 PM com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.TcpIpJoiner
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [0.5.1] [127.0.0.1]:5703 is added to the blacklist.
Mar 07, 2018 1:22:26 PM com.hazelcast.system
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [0.5.1] Cluster version set to 3.9
Mar 07, 2018 1:22:26 PM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.ClusterService
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [0.5.1] 

Members {size:2, ver:2} [
    Member [127.0.0.1]:5701 - 1ff5fff1-4f5e-46f7-b78a-7c0797bc517d
    Member [127.0.0.1]:5702 - b16dad63-03ef-4c6d-b53f-73529a618c7f this
]

Mar 07, 2018 1:22:28 PM com.hazelcast.internal.jmx.ManagementService
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [0.5.1] Hazelcast JMX agent enabled.
Mar 07, 2018 1:22:28 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [0.5.1] [127.0.0.1]:5702 is STARTED
JetInstanceImpl
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastException: Service with name 'hz:impl:jetService' not found!
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1895)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.Job.lambda$join$0(Job.java:72)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.util.Util.uncheckRun(Util.java:94)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.Job.join(Job.java:72)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.IMAP_to_Kafka_Topic.StartIngestion.main(StartIngestion.java:53)
Caused by: com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastException: Service with name 'hz:impl:jetService' not found!
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.NodeEngineImpl.getService(NodeEngineImpl.java:382)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.Operation.getService(Operation.java:293)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.operation.AsyncExecutionOperation.beforeRun(AsyncExecutionOperation.java:55)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:188)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:409)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:115)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.run(OperationThread.java:100)
    at ------ submitted from ------.(Unknown Source)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolve(InvocationFuture.java:127)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture$1.run(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:64)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:80)
Caused by: com.hazelcast.spi.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: Service with name 'hz:impl:jetService' not found!
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.NodeEngineImpl.getService(NodeEngineImpl.java:382)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.Operation.getService(Operation.java:293)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.operation.AsyncExecutionOperation.beforeRun(AsyncExecutionOperation.java:55)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:188)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:409)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:115)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.run(OperationThread.java:100)
Mar 07, 2018 2:19:51 PM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.ClusterHeartbeatManager
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [0.5.1] System clock apparently jumped from 2018-03-07 13:54:23.840 to 2018-03-07 14:19:51.525 since last heartbeat (+1522685 ms)
Mar 07, 2018 2:19:51 PM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.ClusterHeartbeatManager
```

I bumped into a similar question on stackoverflow but that was about

> Service with name'hz:impl:cacheService' not found

Can some on guide me to a solution, on how to solve this exception!

Comment: It looks like you are joining Jet and Hazelcast members in the same cluster. Could you check?

Comment: @Can Gencer, as you can see the stacktrace I have two members joining to the same cluster. What's the problem with this can you please explain a little. May be you could answer to the question with an explanation itself.

Comment: You have two members but one looks like it's a normal Hazelcast instance and the other is a Jet instance. You shouldn't mix these two.